# mongoose connect password must be string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, environment-variables

This is my .env

```
DB_DATABASE="xyz_datatbase"
DB_USERNAME="xyz_user"
DB_PASSWORD="xyz_password"
```

In index.js i am using above env const but i am getting error password must be string even though it is string, i checked with typeof process.env.DB_PASSWORD and i get string

```
// config.db.url = mongodb://localhost/
mongoose.connect(config.db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    dbName: process.env.DB_DATABASE || '',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.DB_USERNAME || '',
        pass: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || '',
    },
});
```

Error in console

```
(node:28764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: password must be a string
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\test\test-app-node-js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:830:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\test\test-app-node-js\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\test-app-node-js\server\server.js:10:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

Comment: If you are using mongoose, you don't need to pass `user, pass` in `auth` you can set `user, pass` at the top level of options object

Comment: where in top level ?

Comment: I've put it as an answer to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)
You can specify `user` and `pass` at the top level of options, like this

```
// config.db.url = mongodb://localhost/
mongoose.connect(config.db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    dbName: process.env.DB_DATABASE || '',
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME || '',
    pass: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || '',
});
```

Comment: With this changes everything is cool but now i am getting authentication failed. i cross checked password still i can't figure out where i did mistake in setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you store data or env variables in .env file you should not enclose it in double-quotes, your codes should be like this,
`DB_DATABASE=xyz_datatbase`
`DB_USERNAME=xyz_user`
`DB_PASSWORD=xyz_password`